# SensorKit - Fetching data don't call results delegate function

Tags: ios, swift

Recently we got approved by Apple to use SensorKit. Here are all prerequisites I checked:

- I'm pretty sure the project is configured properly. Entitlements file contains list of all sensors, Info.plist contains `NSSensorKitUsageDescription`, `NSSensorKitUsageDetail` and `NSSensorKitPrivacyPolicyURL`.
- When I request authorization for a sensor (e.g. accelerometer) the system dialog is presented, I approve it and it's clearly allowed in phone `Settings -> Privacy -> Research Sensor & Usage Data` section
- I started recording for a sensor
- I waited more than 24h (6 days actually)
- I created `SRFetchRequest` (see the code below) with correct time interval

```
let now = Date()
let from = Date(timeInterval: -3 * 24 * 60 * 60, since: now) as NSDate
let to = Date(timeInterval: -2 * 24 * 60 * 60, since: now) as NSDate

let request = SRFetchRequest()
request.device = SRDevice.current
request.from = from.srAbsoluteTime
request.to = to.srAbsoluteTime
reader.fetch(request)
```

What's interesting, no error is triggered. Actually the `func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, didCompleteFetch fetchRequest: SRFetchRequest)` delegate method is invoked but `func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, fetching fetchRequest: SRFetchRequest, didFetchResult result: SRFetchResult<AnyObject>) -> Bool` method never gets called.

Did anyone make it working? Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: could be something else, but.... [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sensorkit/srfetchrequest) say these two things: `1. A fetch query can retrieve only sensor data that the app records by first calling startRecording().` and `2. SensorKit places a 24-hour holding period on newly recorded data before an app can access it. This gives the user an opportunity to delete any data they don’t want to share with the app. A fetch request doesn’t return any results if its time range overlaps this holding period.`.

Comment: Actually I start the recording from a sensor but forgot to mention it in my question. Good catch. I don't get any data even after 24h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested I found an issue. I tried to collect them from my Apple Watch series 3 that are probably not supported. With series 6 (or from iPhone) it works correctly. Interestingly devices support isn't documented anywhere...